# Set default selection option with props

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm having some trouble setting a default value I have tried the following:
add selected in an option

```html
<option value="1" selected>option A</option>
```

This did not work, below is an example of my code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>

      <div class="sm:col-span-3">
        <label
          for="outside_state"
          class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-white"
        >
          Option List
        </label>
        <div class="mt-1">
          <select
          v-model="selector.options"
            id="outside_state"
            name="outside_state"
            class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md dark:text-gray-900"
          >
            <option value="1">Value A</option>
            <option value="1">Value B</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['selector'],
};
</script>
```

How could I set `Value A` as a default value?
Now when the page loads nothing is selected.

Comment: Did you checked this one? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select You need to have the value bound to `v-model`. Meanwhile, be careful of not mutating the value since it's a prop here, ESlint should warn you if you do mutate it. `selected` is useful for HTML, but is not related to Vue state anyhow. Also, you can set defaults in your prop, as shown here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#props

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set default value for props if the props is not being passed it will automatically get that value.

```
props:{
 selector: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({ options: 1 })
    }
}
```

You can read more about props here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types

Comment: Still, it doesn't change the fact that there will be a mutation here at some point.

Comment: Yes, I think the better solution will be to assign the prop value to ref and bind that to a v-model and emit the updated result to keep the data consistent.

Comment: It's tagged with [tag:nuxt] here, so exclusive to vue2 only. `ref` have a different meaning here (template $refs). Also yeah, I'd probably wipe the `v-model` too, in favor of a regular prop + event for more flexibility.